# Change the width of the block with a fixed position

Tags: html, css, sass

On the page I have a block (div element) with fixed position and full-screen width, it looks fine until I add another block (navigation). At this moment my block slides right and some elements in it become not reachable. Maybe you know how to save it full-width property, but also not sliding.

CSS properties of it:

```
.page {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

````
.page {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```
````

Comment: Thank you, it's definitely prevent block from sliding, but I also need to make it smaller when navigation block appears, but using your code it lay above .page

Comment: you can upvote my answer as usefull

Comment: or show me your code i will try to fix it